# Model binding fails in webapi 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, special-characters, query-string, model-binding, webapi2

I am using Webapi 2.0. I am passing one parameter having value as vb/c4t+UuRLnQ2W/g8SQ== After model binding i am getting the value of authId in my code as vb/c4t UuRLnQ2W/g8SQ== The (+) sign gets replaced with a space. Could you please help me out how can i get that.

Url: api/employee/1234?authId=vb/c4t+UuRLnQ2W/g8SQ==

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string eid, string authId)
{
}
```

Comment: you are doing a get operation here and mentioned like post model binding what exactly you are using ?and where you are passing your eid?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, I mean after model binding referred as Post Model binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` sign has a different meaning in the query string. It is used to represent a space. Another character that has semantic importance in the query string is `&` which is used to separate the various `var=value` pairs in the query string.

Most server side scripts would decode the query parameters before using them, so that a `+` gets properly converted to a space. Now, if you want a literal `+` to be present in the query string, you need to specify `%2B` instead.

Example `yourString.replace("+","%2b")`

Alternative method : You should `URLEncode` your query string values to make sure you are not loosing the content.

Another alternate way is like create your own code for `+` sign. for example `12sfdhjsj8722nsn2232dfsdd` will represent a `+` sign. so you can replace the + sign with the code and in your server side you can get it back using the same code.

Comment: happy to help u